# Is there a way to activate (inhibit-message) only for particular modes or buffers?

Tags: inhibit-message

Is there any way to turn on (inhibit-message) only for particular modes or buffers or frames or windows? (any of those would do)

Answer (score 5):

`inhibit-message` is a variable (added in 25.1), not a function (I mention this because you've written it like a function call).

Therefore you can set its value buffer-locally:

```el
(setq-local inhibit-message t)
```

Where you would do that would depend on your specific requirements.

For a particular mode you can use the associated mode hook. For `foo-mode` you would use:

```el
(add-hook 'foo-mode-hook 'my-inhibit-buffer-messages)

(defun my-inhibit-buffer-messages ()
  "Set `inhibit-message' buffer-locally."
  (setq-local inhibit-message t))
```

Note that a more typical use for the variable would be to `let`-bind it around some specific code:

```el
(let ((inhibit-message t))
  ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I add `inhibit-message` to a file as a local variable, it works as desired. However, defining a function and calling it via a mode-hook (as above) doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Experimentally it works for me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it working now. Checking.