# Problems with inhibit-message

Tags: minibuffer, echo-area, inhibit-message

I'm attempting to suppress certain minibuffer messages, but can't seem to get my configuration to work. There are two stack exchange answers that address this ([here](https://superuser.com/a/927832/854775) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27773/20317)) and both suggest using a `let`-binding.

For instance, I've tried running `emacs -Q` and in the `*scratch*` buffer using this:

```lisp
(let ((inhibit-message t))
  (message "End of buffer"))
```

Then, I evaluate the expression with `C-x C-e` and cursor down, but I still see `End of buffer` in the minibuffer. What seems even stranger to me is that running `C-x C-e` in the first place also caused the string to appear in the minibuffer even though `inhibit-message` is locally non-nil.

On a related note, I don't understand on a theoretical level how the `let` form would achieve the desired affect here. As I understand it, when the `let` expression is encountered `inhibit-message` is locally bound to `t` and then the `message` function is called with the string argument, which would have no effect on the minibuffer since `inhibit-message` is non-nil (which is apparently wrong because `C-x C-e` causes the message to appear). However, when this same message is called another time, I don't see why the message should be suppressed. This expression doesn't cause all calls to `(message "End of buffer")` to be evaluated within this `let` does it? If so, how does it? Am I missing the mechanism entirely?

Comment: I don't understand how this is a duplicate of the linked question. My main question here is how to inhibit certain annoying messages from appearing in the minibuffer. The part about the operation of `C-x C-e` and `let` was a side question asked to better understand how the primary goal could be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion is on account of using <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd>

> C-x C-e runs the command eval-last-sexp (found in global-map), which
>   is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘elisp-mode.el’.
>
> It is bound to C-x C-e.
>
> (eval-last-sexp EVAL-LAST-SEXP-ARG-INTERNAL)
>
> Evaluate sexp before point; **print value in the echo area.**
>   Interactively, with a non ‘-’ prefix argument, print output into
>   current buffer.

What you are seeing in the echo area is not the normal message display (which was inhibited), but *the return value of the form you have evaluated*:

```
(let ((inhibit-message t))
  (message "End of buffer"))
```

In this case the return value will be that of the final form of the `let` expression, which is the call to `message`:

> message is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> (message FORMAT-STRING &rest ARGS)
>
> Display a message at the bottom of the screen.
>   The message also goes into the ‘*Messages*’ buffer, if ‘message-log-max’
>   is non-nil.  (In keyboard macros, that’s all it does.)
>   **Return the message.**

As indicated by the `eval-last-sexp` docstring, if you use a prefix arg the return value will be inserted into the buffer rather than displayed in the echo area; so you can test this with:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd>

---

> On a related note, I don't understand on a theoretical level how the let form would achieve the desired affect here.

We don't know what your desired effect is.

> As I understand it, when the let expression is encountered inhibit-message is locally bound to t and then the message function is called with the string argument, which would have no effect on the minibuffer since inhibit-message is non-nil [...] However, when this same message is called another time, I don't see why the message should be suppressed. This expression doesn't cause all calls to (message "End of buffer") to be evaluated within this let does it?

I think you've understood correctly.

```
(let ((inhibit-message t))
  (message "End of buffer"))
```

affects that one single call to `message`

If you subsequently call `(message "End of buffer")` outside of that `let` form, that subsequent message is not inhibited.

Comment: My desired effect is that I'd like to prevent `End of buffer` from ever being displayed in the minibuffer, but allow it to display in the `*Messages*` buffer, per normal. If this won't  do that, is there another way to achieve that effect?

Comment: To do that with `inhibit-message` you'd need to cause it to be non-nil whenever the code which generated that message was evaluated.

Comment: @MattHusz See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20039/9970)